# DROOLS - double amount

Tags: drools

I am creating a condition like the following:

```
$event : EventObject(type=='Sale', $points:points, $playerid:playerid) from 
entry-point eventstream
```

The consequence of this I need to pass the variables to the following:

```
boolean givePointsToPlayer(String playerId,
                         String pointType,
                         double amount,
                         String notificationMessage)
```

The most basic example below is me giving 3 points to this player

```
updateAPIv1.givePointsToPlayer($playerid, 'Points', 3, 'Points Awarded');
update(engine.getPlayerById($playerid));
```

However, I want to pass the $points:points to 'double amount'.

Simple question I know but how best would I do this? Something like?

```
    $points=double amount;
updateAPIv1.givePointsToPlayer($playerid, 'Points', amount, 'Points Awarded');
update(engine.getPlayerById($playerid));;
```

Appreciate feedback. Thanks.

***Update I tried also

```
 $event : EventObject(type=='Sale', $points:points, $playerid:playerid)  
             from entry-point eventstream    

 updateAPIv1.givePointsToPlayer($playerid, 'Points', $points, 'Points Awarded');
 update(engine.getPlayerById($playerid));
```

but I get the following errors for this

```
 "Unable to create Field Extractor for 'points'
  Field/method 'points' not found for class  'com.sap.gamification.model.EventObject"  
  "Rule Compilation error $points cannot be resolved "
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should very quickly catch up on Java syntax, since this is an invalid statement.

```
$points=double amount;
```

However, you do not need to store the value of a bound variable (`$points`) to another variable in the consequence. You can write this call:

```
updateAPIv1.givePointsToPlayer($playerid, 'Points', $points, 'Points Awarded');
```

Think of variables bound to fact fields as "final" variables: you can access the value but not change it.

**Edit** This assumes that you have:

```
public class EventObject {
     private double points;
     public double getPoints(){ return points; }
     // ... rest of class
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have tried that and it did not work, for example:    $event : EventObject(type=='Sale', $points:points, $playerid:playerid) from entry-point eventstreamupdateAPIv1.givePointsToPlayer($playerid, 'Points', $points, 'Points Awarded');
update(engine.getPlayerById($playerid));